# Context state being updated unexpectedly - React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, state, react-context

First time poster so let me know if more information is need.

Trying to figure out why my global state using context API is being updated even when my setSate method is commented out. I thought i might have been mutating the state directly accidently but I dont believe I am

"specialModes" in actionOnClick() is the state in question

```
const SpecialFunctions: FC = (props: Props) => {
const { currentModeContext, specialModesContext: specialActionsContext, performCalc, inputValueContext } = useContext(AppContext)
const { specialModes, setSpecialModes } = specialActionsContext
const { currentMode, setCurrentMode } = currentModeContext
const { inputValue, setInputValue } = inputValueContext

const categoryOnClick = (index: number) => {
    setCurrentMode(specialModes[index])
    console.log(specialModes[index].title);
}

const actionOnClick = (action: IAction) => {
    let newAction = action
    newAction.value = performCalc()
    let newSpecialModes = specialModes.map((mode) => {
        if (mode === currentMode) {
            let newMode = mode
            newMode.actions = mode.actions.map((element) => {
                if (element === action) {
                    return newAction
                }
                else return element
            })
            return newMode
        }
        else return mode

    })
    //setSpecialModes(newSpecialModes)

}

let headings = specialModes.map((categorgy, index) => {
    return <Heading isActive={categorgy === currentMode ? true : false} onClick={() => categoryOnClick(index)} key={index}>{categorgy.title}</Heading>
})

let actions = currentMode.actions.map((action, index) => {
    return (
        <Action key={index} onClick={() => actionOnClick(action)}>
            <ActionTitle>{action.title}</ActionTitle>
            <ActionValue>{action.value}</ActionValue>
        </Action>
    )
})
return (
    <Wrapper>
        <Category>
            {headings}
        </Category>
        <ActionsWrapper toggleRadiusCorner={currentMode === specialModes[0] ? false : true}>
            {actions}
        </ActionsWrapper>

    </Wrapper>
)
```

}

Context.tsx

```
interface ContextType {
specialModesContext: {
    specialModes: Array<ISpecialModes>,
    setSpecialModes: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<ISpecialModes[]>>
},
currentModeContext: {
    currentMode: ISpecialModes,
    setCurrentMode: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<ISpecialModes>>
},
inputValueContext: {
    inputValue: string,
    setInputValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>
},
inputSuperscriptValueContext: {
    inputSuperscriptValue: string,
    setInputSuperscriptValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>
},
performCalc: () => string
}

export const AppContext = createContext({} as ContextType);

export const ContextProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
const [SpecialModes, setSpecialModes] = useState([
    {
        title: 'Rafter',
        actions: [
            {
                title: 'Span',
                active: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Ridge Thickness',
                active: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Pitch',
                active: false
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        title: 'General',
        actions: [
            {
                title: 'General1',
                active: false
            },
            {
                title: 'General2',
                active: false
            },
            {
                title: 'General3',
                active: false
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        title: 'Stairs',
        actions: [
            {
                title: 'Stairs1',
                active: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Stairs2',
                active: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Stairs3',
                active: false
            }
        ],
    }
] as Array<ISpecialModes>)

const [currentMode, setCurrentMode] = useState(SpecialModes[0])

const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('0')
const [inputSuperscriptValue, setInputSuperscriptValue] = useState('')

const replaceCharsWithOperators = (string: string): string => {
    let newString = string.replaceAll(/\s/g, '') // delete white space 
    newString = newString.replace('×', '*')
    newString = newString.replace('÷', '/')
    console.log(string)
    console.log(newString)
    return newString
}

const performCalc = (): string => {
    let originalEquation = `${inputSuperscriptValue} ${inputValue} =`
    let equation = inputSuperscriptValue + inputValue
    let result = ''
    equation = replaceCharsWithOperators(equation)
    result = eval(equation).toString()
    setInputSuperscriptValue(`${originalEquation} ${result}`)
    setInputValue(result)
    console.log(result)
    return result
}

return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={
        {
            specialModesContext: {
                specialModes: SpecialModes,
                setSpecialModes: setSpecialModes
            },
            currentModeContext: {
                currentMode,
                setCurrentMode
            },
            inputValueContext: {
                inputValue,
                setInputValue
            },
            inputSuperscriptValueContext: {
                inputSuperscriptValue,
                setInputSuperscriptValue
            },
            performCalc
        }}>
        {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
)
}
```

Comment: I cannot see problem here, maybe attach provider and context declaration files so we could help :)

Comment: I have added my Context.tsx to the post, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `mode.actions.map()` function you are indirectly changing `actions` field of your original `specialModes` array.

To fix this problem you need to create shallow copy of `specialModes` array Using the `...` ES6 spread operator.

```
const clonedSpecialModes = [...specialModes];
let newSpecialModes = clonedSpecialModes.map((mode) => { 
    // rest of your logic here
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I have messed around with similar solutions and just tried this one with no luck. State still seems to be getting updated somehwere

Comment: Okay, Can you try with json parse and see if it works for you. something like `const clonedSpecialModes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(specialModes))`

Comment: Finally figured it out. I was accidently mutating state from parsing it to a function as a variable and using it there. Made a shallow copy of it there and fixed the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great! I am happy to help.